# read variable hostname from file

Tags: python

i want to read a hostname from a file and use it on my python script to make make a rest api call

```
server_list = []
with open('U4P.txt', 'r') as f:
    for server_ip in f:
        server_ip = server_ip.rstrip()
    server_list.append(server_ip)
    for server_ip in server_list:
     ru = U4VConn(server_name='server_ip', port=8443,verify=False, username='san', password='xxxxx')
```

the result show no ip instead it show the variable name server_ip
PyU4V.rest_requests - ERROR - The GET request to URL https://server_ip:8443/univmax/restapi/84/sloprovisioning/symmetrix

Comment: You are passing the literal string `'server_ip'` as the server name, not the value of the variable `server_ip`. Drop the quotes.

Comment: Thank you very Chepner.

Comment: this work fine as long as i have only one IP if i add other IP's in the text file the loop print me the last item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an indentantion error and an unneeded quote.

```
server_list = []
with open('U4P.txt', 'r') as f:
    for server_ip in f:
        server_ip = server_ip.rstrip()
        server_list.append(server_ip) #here the indentation error
    for server_ip in server_list:
        ru = U4VConn(server_name=server_ip, port=8443,verify=False, username='san', password='xxxxx')
                            #^^^^^^^^^ here the unneded quotes
```

Due to the indentation error you were saving in your list only the last server in our file. This is why you were getting only one server.
Due to the quotes, you were using the string `'server_ip'` as server name, and not the server name itself. `server_ip` must be a variable.

Comment: You're welcome. [If the answer was helpul, please consider to accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the value of server_ip anywhere in your program. You almost do, but you accidentally made it into a string by calling `'server_ip'`.

You probably want the following instead.

```py
server_list = []
with open('U4P.txt', 'r') as f:
    for server_ip in f:
        server_ip = server_ip.rstrip()
    server_list.append(server_ip)
    for server_ip in server_list:
        ru = U4VConn(server_name=server_ip,  # Note that there are no quotes
                     port=8443,
                     verify=False,
                     username='san',
                     password='xxxxx')
```

Comment: David, by changing 'server_ip'. to server_ip this work fine as long as my U4P.txt have only one server if i add servers it will print the last iterm belonging to that server. the output for 1 server is:   [u'000000000429', u'000000000623', u'000000000670', u'000000000677', u'000000000686', u'000000001979', u'000000002070', u'000000002255', u'000000002257'] now i f i add more IP in the text file i get  only [u'000000000113'] this item